# why goland recognize merge-base as a command

Tags: git, goland

why goland recognize `merge-base`  as a command.
is ok when i exec `/usr/local/bin/golangci-lint run -c ~/.golangci.yml -v --new-from-rev=$(git merge-base origin/master HEAD)` in `term`

```
/usr/local/bin/golangci-lint run -c ~/.golangci.yml -v --new-from-rev=$(git merge-base origin/master HEAD)
level=info msg="[config_reader] Used config file ../../../../../../../../.golangci.yml"
level=info msg="[lintersdb] Active 20 linters: [deadcode dupl errcheck goconst gosec gosimple govet ineffassign lll misspell prealloc rowserrcheck scopelint staticcheck structcheck stylecheck typecheck unconvert unused varcheck]"
level=info msg="[loader] Go packages loading at mode 575 (deps|exports_file|name|types_sizes|compiled_files|files|imports) took 37.710305ms"
level=error msg="Running error: context loading failed: failed to load packages: cannot find package \"git.company.cn/.../account.oper/merge-base\" in any of:\n\t/usr/local/go/src/git.company.cn/.../account.oper/merge-base (from $GOROOT)\n\t/Users/liupengfei/go/src/git.company.cn/.../account.oper/merge-base(from $GOPATH): failed to analyze"
level=info msg="Memory: 2 samples, avg is 71.8MB, max is 71.8MB"
level=info msg="Execution took 51.886435ms"
```

Comment: What terminal (zsh, fish, etc.) are you using in GoLand and locally?

Comment: `git merge-base` *is* a command. So if something *is* recognizing it *as* a command, that something seems to be behaving correctly. If you meant to ask why it is *not* recognizing it as a command, that would be sensible question for the goland people, perhaps.

Comment: @s0xzwasd goland and locally and both zsh

Comment: look at the error  ```merge-base```,  is recognize the ```go packages.``` @torek

Comment: The only "error" I see is "failed to load". That does not seem to be a question of recognition, nor of failure to recognize. My point in the comment, however, was that your posting essentially says that it "is" working, not that it "is not" working. I suspect a translation issue. Note: I'm seeing this under the [tag:git] tag, not the [tag:goland] tag. I have never used goland.